# Substitute @page (CSS) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to use some CSS that includes @page. (I want to insert a header and a footer on all printed pages)

As you can see here https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-paged-media @page does not work on all browsers. Therefore I prefere a solution with jQuery. Does anybody know if I can use jQuery for inserting content to all headers and footers of the printed version of a website?

[EDIT] With @media print i can do a lot of things, but I cannot insert a header and a footer on top/ bottom of each printed page. If i insert the header at the beginning and the footer at the end (using prepend and append / jquery) and style it by usinf CSS (@media print) it is no problem. But the task is to insert it to each printed (!) page.

With @page i have two disadvantages: 
1) The poor browser-support
2) the fact that I cannot display the header/ footer with a width of 100%. There are only some places for inserting content (@top-left, @bottom-left, but nothing width  100%width of page. 
[/EDIT]

Comment: Why don't you use `@media print`?

Comment: I edited my question in order to answer.

Comment: Insert a custom header and a custom footer in your HTML, which both should be hidden (using `display: none`). Then you could use `@media print` to display them.